# REST запрос c аутентификацией с помощью библиотеки Axios

Tags: javascript, rest, request, auth, axios

Все не могу сформировать запрос с помощью библиотеки [Axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios)

**Command line:**

curl -u 5621.z5fcb4f1d0574b36e9f54969704efced16dc83bfff807e181176890aa71b75f:X https://api.woodpecker.co/rest/v1/campaign_list

**Axios:**

```
axios.get('https://api.woodpecker.co/rest/v1/campaign_list', {
    headers: {'Authorization': '5621.z5fcb4f1d0574b36e9f54969704efced16dc83bfff807e181176890aa71b75f:X'}
})
.then(function(response) {
   console.log(response.status)
})
.catch(function(err) {
   console.log(err)
})
```

API_KEY дал не верный. Думаю понимаете из-за чего.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исходя с [документации](http://help.woodpecker.co/article/16-api-docs):

> The API Key is passed via HTTP Basic Authentication and goes in the
>   username field. A dummy password, such as X, goes in the password
>   field

это означает что хедер будет выглядеть как:

```
Authorization: Basic base64(user:pass)
```

берете апи кей и дамми пасс и заходите https://www.base64decode.org/ кодируете Вашу строку: `api-key:pass` и делаете запрос к апи:

```
axios.get('https://api.woodpecker.co/rest/v1/campaign_list', {
    headers: {'Authorization': 'Basic bas64-нутая-строка-из-apikey:pass'}
})
.then(function(response) {
   console.log(response.status)
})
.catch(function(err) {
   console.log(err)
})
```

P.S. Для удобства можете пользоваться [postman](https://www.getpostman.com/apps)-ом который поможет Вам тестировать апи и генерирует нужные хедеры

[image: постман шаг 1]

[image: постман шаг 2]

Comment: спасибо за ответ. в postman'е данные получил и взял с него заголовок: **Basic NzIzNS5hNWZjYjRmMWQwNTc1YjM2ZTlmYjQ5NjkwMDRlZmNlZDE2ZGM4M2JmZmY4MDdlZjg3Njg5MGFhZjU5YjFiNzVmOlg=** но все та же ошибка в консоле - https://ibb.co/gLkmKk
Добавлял в заголовок еще это **'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*'** но не помогло.

Comment: @АртемГолинка этот апи не для коммуникации фронтенд <=> их апи. посколько никто не шлет креденциалы в открытую. подумайте о том чтоб сделать серверсайд обращение и выведите в какой то роут и оттуда отсылайте. А хедер `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` ставит принимающая сторона для того чтоб "сказать" клиент стороне что можно что нет

Comment: ок, спасибо за ответ. я вас понял